# MySQL: Unique multi-column index and NULL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with user-email-addresses (TINYTEXT) and locations of shops (just an INT). Every email-address should be unique in each location, so it's allowed:

```
test@example.com on location 1
test@example.com on location 2
test@example.com on location 3
but not:
test@example.com on location 1
test@example.com on location 1
```

So I created an index like:

```
UNIQUE KEY email_per_location(email, location)
```

which worked fine so far and throws an error if I add an email-adrress-location-combination which already exists.

Now I want to add users which should have access to all locations. I don't want to add one for every location, so the idea was to set location to NULL for that like:

```
test@example.com on location 1 -> Has access to location 1 
test@example.com on location 2 -> Has access to location 2 
admin@example.com on location NULL -> Has access to ALL locations
```

The problem with my index:

```
UNIQUE KEY email_per_location(email, location)
```

is, that this would not throw an error (but it should):

```
admin@example.com on location 1 -> Has access to location 1 
admin@example.com on location NULL -> Has access to ALL locations
```

Is it possible to create an index (or something else?) that doesn't allow this situation?

Added: If there is a good solution for using another value for "all locations" (not the NULL value) this would be fine as well.

Comment: The problem with using `NULL` in this way is that semantically it means "unknown."  Hence, when comparing a location against `NULL` for equality, MySQL reports that it doesn't know, and returns false.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I understand, why MySQL does it, but how can I avoid it? ;-) I could use something like "location=0" or "location=-1" as well for "all locations", but this wouldn't prevent from inserting the same email with another location.

Comment: The thing is, what you are trying to do is codify information in a _single_ record from which MySQL can determine whether _multiple_ records might be duplicates.  This seems to be breaking normalization.  I would personally store one record for each email/location relationship.